# Which part of speech should I use for a "from-to" construction?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Ignoring that the "from-to" construction in this sentence doesn't describe a true range, can someone explain whether I'd use present-tense verbs or gerunds, and why? I know what sounds right, but I can't put my finger on the rule.

The apps help you do everything from **creating** projects to **transforming** presentations.
*or* 
The apps help you do everything from **create** projects to **transform** presentations.

Comment: Since you are talking about things, the first version with a gerund/participle is better

Comment: It could also be: *These apps help you with everything, from the **creation** of projects to the **transformation** of presentations.* In fact, I think I personally prefer that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is grammatically correct because there are two prepositions (**from** and **to**) which can be used only with nouns and pronouns (the latter ones can be sometimes omitted but easily reconstructed from the context).

'Ing-form' in your case is termed the 'Gerund' or 'Verbal Noun' and is often used with the preposition.

As a part of speech 
the Gerund belongs to Infinite (i.e. Impersonal) Verb Forms like the Infinitive and Participles.